# Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4 how to remove this message when compiling in java

Tags: javafx

I compiled my first `helloworld.java` program using javaFx. The program works, but I got this message:

```
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
```

I would like to know what does this message mean and how to remove it
I am using a light version of Ubuntu (Lubuntu 15.04) with

- kernel 13.19.0-21-generic (i686)
- java version "1.8.0_45" Java(TM) SE
- Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
- Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
- javac -version javac 1.8.0_45

Any help about how to get along with this `Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4` is appreciated.

Comment: The Bug is scheduled to be fixed in Java 9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088421

Comment: Is it a Bug?, will be fixed in Java 9?